# Appending command line argument to a script in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, typeorm, package.json

I am using a package.json to run my migrations in TypeORM (0.3.x). But there we need to specify a path which has the path to migrations folder and the migration name.

E.g. if we want to store the migration in 'src/migrations' and migration name is 'aaa' , we have to give the path as 'src/migrations/aaa'.

But I want to insert migration name ('aaa' in above example) as an argument. How to do it? I am using Windows 10.

```json
 "scripts": {
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli",    
    "db:migration:generate": "npm run typeorm  -- -d ./orm.migration.config.ts  migration:generate ",  
    "db:migration:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run -- -d ./orm.migration.config.ts",
    "db:migration:undo": "npm run typeorm migration:revert -- -d ./orm.migration.config.ts",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you would want to pass down parameters/arguments to the underlying script while running it with `npm`.

With Powershell, you can achieve it by using double hypens OR triple hyphens, depending on the version of Node you're using. More about that [here](https://www.lloydatkinson.net/posts/2022/powershell-npm-scripts-and-silently-dropped-arguments/).

For a practical example: `npm run typeorm -- aaa`.

If that doesn't work, try with try triple hyphens: `npm run typeorm --- aaa`.

Comment: No this doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit further? What does not work? Do you have any error? What does the command looks like when you invoke `npm run typeorm`? What have you tried so far?